# How to change the color of ArrayList elements in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to change the color of the elements of Array List. Below is my code

```
{
                    List<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
                    String firstNumber = edtFNum.getText().toString();
                    String secondNumber = edt2Num.getText().toString();
                    for (int i = Integer.parseInt(firstNumber); i <= Integer.parseInt(secondNumber); i++) {
                        boolean isPrime = true;
                        for (int j = 2; j <= i / 2; j++) {
                            if (i % j == 0) {
                                isPrime = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (isPrime) {
                            primeNumbers.add(i);

                        }
                    }
                    txtResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
                    String formattedString = primeNumbers.toString()
                            .replace("[", "")
                            .replace("]", "")
                            .trim();
                    txtResult.setText("Prime numbers between " + firstNumber + " and " + secondNumber + " are: " + formattedString);
```

I want to change to color of "Prime numbers between" to Red and choose alternative color for each item of the arraylist i.e Blue for ist element and Green for 2nd and so on. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use spanning for decorating your text, e.g. for your case color of (part of) text may be changed using [`ForegroundColorSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan), like this:

```
Spannable textToSetAsSpan = new SpannableString("Prime numbers between " + firstNumber + 
    " and " + secondNumber + " are: " + formattedString);        
textToSetAsSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(textToSetAsSpan);
```

just properly calculate position of your numbers in text and adjust color :)